# Read from .txt file containing executable commands to be executed w/ output of commands executed sent to another file

Tags: bash

When I run my script, the .txt file is read, the executable commands are assigned to `$eggs`, then to execute the commands and redirect the output to a file I use `echo $eggs>>eggsfile.txt` but when I cat the file, I just see all the commands and not the execution output of those commands.

```
echo "Hi, $USER"
cd ~/mydata
echo -e "Please enter the name of commands file:/s"
read fname               
if [ -z "$fname" ]
then
  exit
fi

terminal=`tty`       

exec < $fname              #exec destroys current shell, opens up new shell process where FD0 (STDIN) input comes from file fname

count=1

while read line
do
  echo $count.$line                   #count line numbers
  count=`expr $count + 1`; eggs="${line#[[:digit:]]*}";
  touch ~/mydata/eggsfile.txt; echo $eggs>>eggsfile.txt; echo "Reading eggsfile contents: $(cat eggsfile.txt)"
done

exec < $terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to execute the commands, and log the command name before each command, you can use 'sh -x'. You will get '+ command' before each command.

```
sh -x commands

+pwd
/home/user
+ date
Sat Apr  4 21:15:03 IDT 2020
```

If you want to build you own (custom formatting, etc),  you will have to force execution of each command. Something like:

```
cd ~/mydata
count=0
while read line ; do
    count=$((count+1))
    echo "$count.$line"
    eggs="${line#[[:digit:]]*}"
    echo "$eggs" >> eggsfile.txt
    # Execute the line.
    ($line) >> eggsfile.txt
done < $fname
```

Note that this approach uses local redirection for the `while` loop, avoiding having to revert the input back to the terminal.